# Failed to install rqt-plot

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to install rqt-plot (I am running ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04).

When running `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rqt-plot`  I get the following error:

> Err:1
> http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu
> xenial/main amd64
> ros-kinetic-qt-gui-py-common amd64
> 0.3.11-0xenial-20180830-074357-0800   404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134
> 80]

Err:2

> http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu
> xenial/main amd64
> ros-kinetic-qwt-dependency amd64
> 1.1.0-0xenial-20180809-134545-0800   404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134
> 80]

Err:3

> http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu
> xenial/main amd64
> ros-kinetic-rqt-py-common amd64
> 0.5.0-0xenial-20190320-153730-0800   404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134
> 80]

Err:4

> http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu
> xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-rqt-plot
> amd64
> 0.4.8-0xenial-20190320-171954-0800   404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134
> 80]

E: Failed to fetch

> http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-qt-gui-py-common/ros-kinetic-qt-gui-py-common_0.3.11-0xenial-20180830-074357-0800_amd64.deb
> 404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134
> 80]
>
> E: Failed to fetch
> http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-qwt-dependency/ros-kinetic-qwt-dependency_1.1.0-0xenial-20180809-134545-0800_amd64.deb
> 404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134
> 80]
>
> E: Failed to fetch
> http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-rqt-py-common/ros-kinetic-rqt-py-common_0.5.0-0xenial-20190320-153730-0800_amd64.deb
> 404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134
> 80]
>
> E: Failed to fetch
> http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-rqt-plot/ros-kinetic-rqt-plot_0.4.8-0xenial-20190320-171954-0800_amd64.deb
> 404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134
> 80]
>
> E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

I can ping `packages.ros.org` and `140.211.166.134` , so it doesn't seem to be a connectivity issue...

Any ideas on what's going on and how to fix it and proceed with the installation?

SOLUTION: as commented by @gvdhoorn the key has to be updated as described in #q325039.

Then run `sudo apt update` :

```
Obj:1 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Obj:2 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                                                                                  
Obj:3 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                                                                                                                
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                               
Des:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]                                                                             
Obj:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                      
Des:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial InRelease [4.678 B]                                             
Des:9 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [785 kB]                   
Des:10 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease [23,2 kB]
Ign:10 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease                      
Des:11 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages [561 kB]
Descargados 1.483 kB en 3s (396 kB/s)
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325449/failed-to-install-rqt-plot/) by [iabadia](https://answers.ros.org/users/37308/iabadia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2019-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This could be caused by the issue described in #q325039. Could you check?

If you already have the correct key, can you verify that `sudo apt update` completes successfully? It might help if you post the output of that command here (not in a comment, append it to your original question text, use the `edit` button/link for that).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1